# Laplacian on two Lie groups have the same Lie algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, laplacian

I know that if $G$ is a Lie group and $\mathfrak g = span\{X_i, 1\leq i \leq n\}$ be its Lie algebra, where $\{X_i\}$ are the vector fields of $G$. Then, the Casimir-Laplacian of $G$ is given by 
$$\Delta_{G}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2.$$
Now, if $G_1$ is a Lie group that has the same Lie algebra of another Lie group $G_2$. Is what we have $\Delta_{G_1}=\Delta_{G_2}$ ?

I think yes, because, if $span\{X_i, 1\leq i \leq n\}=\mathfrak g_1 =\mathfrak g_2 =span\{Y_i, 1\leq i \leq n\} $, so $\Delta_{G_1}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 =\Delta_{G_2} $ Is it?

A simple example: the Lie group $G_1=\mathbb S^1$ (the circle) has the same Lie algebra of the Lie group $G_2=\mathbb R$ and we have $\Delta_{\mathbb R}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = \Delta_{\mathbb S^1} $.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not what you want for an arbitrary basis $\{X_i\}$: there should be a non-degenerate bilinear form (Cartan-Killing form?) and the $\{X_i\}$ an orthogonal basis... and coefficients $1/\langle X_i,X_i\rangle$. Or, better yet, one can define the Casimir operator without choosing a basis, just depending on the Lie algebra and the invariant non-degenerate bilinear form.

Comment: I think the better formulation of this is as follows. Let $f:M \to N$ be a covering map of Riemannian manifolds, and a local isometry, i.e. pull back $N$'s metric to put on one $M$. Then since the metric determines the Laplacian, the Laplacians will likewise be the "same". Here, the Lie algebra determines the metric (then determines the Laplacian).